# Why doesn't $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{|x|}$ equal to 1?

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried to solve it like this:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x}{|x|} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}} = 1$$

Why is this wrong?

Comment: The first time you substitute $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$  Right.  The second time, you substitute $x=\sqrt{x^2}$  Wrong.

Comment: Approach it by $x > 0$ and $x < 0$ to see what happens.

Comment: Why didn't you just graph it?
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%2F%7Cx%7C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$ is a negative number, then $x = -\sqrt{x^2}$

$$
   \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}} =
   \begin{cases}
       1 & \text{If $x > 0$} \\
      -1 & \text{If $x < 0$} \\
      \text{Undefined} & \text{If $x = 0$}
   \end{cases}
 $$

Comment: But in the 3rd step for example, aren't $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}}$ equivalent? I've always done it that way for other problems.

Comment: There are conflicting opinions about the meaning of $\sqrt{x^2}$. It's complicated and seemingly inconsistent, so a lot of instructors sort of hand-wave their way around it. My answer is correct. Its use can be argued about, but not its truth.

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire: For example: $\frac{-4}{\sqrt{(-4)^2}} = \frac{-4}{\sqrt{16}} = \frac{-4}{4} = -1$ while $\sqrt{\frac{(-4)^2}{(-4)^2}} = \sqrt 1 = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\frac{x}{|x|}=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $x>0$}\\
-1 &\text{if $x<0$}\\
\end{cases}
$$
So
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x}{|x|}=
\lim_{x\to 0^+} 1 = 1,
$$
but
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{x}{|x|}=
\lim_{x\to 0^-} (-1) = -1.
$$
Because these two values differ, the two-sided limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{|x|}$$ does not exist.